# Adjust Content in ballon div

Tags: css

```
.ballon {
    display:block;
    width: 60%;
    height:300px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-border-radius: 63px 63px 63px 63px / 72px 72px 108px 108px;
    border-radius:         50%  50%  50%  50%  / 40%   40%   60%  60%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

how to center the text in the balloon and not leave the balloon?

How do I add a small triangle after the balloon?

[image]

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nk8m4548/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.ballon {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-border-radius: 63px 63px 63px 63px / 72px 72px 108px 108px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 40% 40% 60% 60%;
  text-align: center;
}

.col-md-4 + .col-md-4 { /* add some space between the columns */
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.ballon:after { /* here we create the triangle */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 8px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ballon > h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  
  <div class="ballon"><h2>Test large content in ballon</h2></div>
  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  
  <div class="ballon"><h2>Test large content in ballon</h2></div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  
  <div class="ballon"><h2>Test large content in ballon</h2></div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the flexbox model to align the content. You can read more on flexbox here: [flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You can play around with the forked fiddle here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ra30s1k/)

I hope this helps you. Otherwise you may tell me in more detail what exactly you want to achieve (even the edge cases).

**EDIT:**
I have edited the snippet in my solution and also updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ra30s1k/2/).

You can find some useful information about the triangles here: [css-triangles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).
Have a look at the [triangle generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) if you don't want to do it manually:

Comment: Thank´s @F.muller , I did not know about flexbox, this is very interesting. I added a picture in my question, after the balloon I need to learn to add a small triangle

Comment: @Gisele You are welcome. Have a look at the `Edit` part in the solution for your second question. Btw. your class is called "ballon" (French) instead of "balloon" (English). I just mention this because you use both variants in your question.

Answer (score 0):

try for text is, do all  this code in css file
add position:relative;  to class ballon
and add this in css file
`h2{position:absolute;top:40%;left:20px;}`